# When will event produced on server with MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM delivered to subscriber on client

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I created an example client/server application to get familiar with Spring Webflux/Reactor Netty. Now I am a little bit confused about the behaviour on the client side when the response contains a Flux and the media type is "text/event-stream". What I could see is that each element produced on the server is sent immediately to the client but not yet delivered to the subscriber. The first delivery to the subscriber happens after the producer of the server side has completed the Flux.
This means for me that all the elements are first collected somewhere in reactor-netty on the client side until it gets a complete/error event.

Are my conclusions true or can i do something wrong there?
If it is true, will this be changed in the near future? With my currently observed behaviour most of the benefits using Spring Webflux are negated because as with Spring Mvc the consumer has to wait until the whole element collection has been created and transfered before he can start working on the elements.

My server app is:`

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(ServerApp.class).run(args);
    }

    @RestController
    public static class TestController {
        @GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
        public Flux<String> testFlux() {
            class AsyncSink implements Consumer<SynchronousSink<String>> {
                private List<String> allStrings = List.of(
                        "Hello Flux1!",
                        "Hello Flux2!",
                        "Hello Flux3!",
                        "Hello Flux4!",
                        "Hello Flux5!");
                private int index = 0;

                @Override
                public void accept(SynchronousSink<String> sink) {
                    if (index == allStrings.size()) {
                        sink.complete();
                    }
                    else {
                        sink.next(allStrings.get(index++));
                    }
                }

            }

            return Flux.generate(new AsyncSink());
        }
    }
}
```

and my client app is:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClientApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext aContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder().web(WebApplicationType.NONE).sources(ClientApp.class).run(args);

        Flux<String> aTestFlux = aContext.getBean(TestProxy.class).getFlux();
        aTestFlux.subscribe(new TestSubscriber());

        System.out.println("Press ENTER to exit.");
        System.in.read();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();
    }

    @Component
    public static class TestProxy {
        @Autowired
        private WebClient webClient;

        public Flux<String> getFlux() {
            return webClient.get().uri("/test").accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM).exchange().flatMapMany(theResponse -> theResponse.bodyToFlux(String.class));
        }
    }

    private static class TestSubscriber extends BaseSubscriber<String> {
        @Override
        public void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
            System.out.println("Subscribed");
            request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        @Override
        public void hookOnNext(String theValue) {
            System.out.println(" - " + theValue);
            request(1);
        }

        @Override
        protected void hookOnComplete() {
            System.out.println("   done");
        }

        @Override
        protected void hookOnCancel() {
            System.out.println("   cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        protected void hookOnError(Throwable theThrowable) {
            theThrowable.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

When i access the url http://localhost:8080/test with chrome browser i see:

```
data:Hello Flux1!

data:Hello Flux2!

data:Hello Flux3!

data:Hello Flux4!

data:Hello Flux5!
```

which for me looks like 5 http event have been sent.

Comment: show us the code

Comment: I have added my test code to the initial question part

Comment: `What I could see is that each element produced on the server is sent immediately to the client but not yet delivered to the subscriber` how did you come to this conclusion? i dont really understand your question.

Comment: I thought that the output of chrome proves it, but it also seems not to be true. I get more and more confused. I changed now my server side generator to emit 100 or even an infinit number of elements and the the client get the first element after the server has emitted about 23 elements.
Therefore my most important question is: What is the current state of reactor-netty concerning synchronization of a large (or infinite) flux over the network.

Comment: the output of chrome shows, 5 elements have been emitted. Your declared list in your application contains 5 items. It emitted the 5 items so i dont see the problem?

Comment: The problem is when the elements are emitted over the network. when i emit an element only every minute on the server chrome does not display any element after the last has been emitted. In other words whenever my sink emits an element it is not directly directed to the subscriber, its somewhere cached and only directed to the consumer if either the sink is completed or a certain amount of elements have been emitted.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the reactive documentation and rewritten to fit your need.

My guess is that in your example you have given you pass the generate function a consumer that when finished will be emitted.

By instead using the method `Flux#generate(Callable<S> stateSupplier, BiFunction<S,SynchronousSink<T>,S> generator)` you supply a state that will contain the items you want emitted, then in the supplied `BiFunction` you emit each item, one by one.

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.generate(
    () -> List.of("1!", "2!", "3!", "4!", "5!"), 
    (state, sink) -> {
        if (index == allStrings.size()) {
            sink.complete();
        } else {
          sink.next(state.get(index++));
        } 
    });
```

I have not tested the code, written on mobile.